# PHP - array search get key value

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have got an array as below,

```
$country = array ("01. USA","02. Russia","03. UK","04. India");
```

and i just wanted to search my array with this string `$str = "USA";` and it should return me the key where the value is. Is that possible. I tried using `array_search()` and its not working.

Update:

The actual array am having,

```
Array ( [0] => 01. Australian Dollar [1] => 06. Swedish Kroner [2] => 02. British Pound Sterling [3] => 07. Swish Frank [4] => 03. Canadian Dollar [5] => 08. U.S. Dollar [6] => 04. Japanese Yen Per 100 [7] => 09. Euro [8] => 05. Singapore Dollar [9] => 10. Taka Per 100 )
```

Comment: "Doesn't work"? What happens when you try it?

Comment: Only manually, there is no built-in function for that

Comment: @ChrisW am just getting an empty screen.

Comment: have you tried `array_walk()` ?

Comment: you could try using `preg_match` with `array_search()`, using a regex statement like `/USA$/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try foreach value test if contains strstr().

```
    foreach ($country as $n => $state)
    {
        if (strstr($state, 'USA'))
        {
            //found
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove the part about big array, add `break`, and key and it will be an ideal answer, +1

Comment: But if he use it on big array (of more than thousand values) it would take more time to process it isn't this right?

Comment: @sczdavos: but you still need to perform that work. What would you say to your boss - the array is too big, I won't do that?

Comment: @zerkms No, I only want to say, that this will take more time to process for big arrays. So if I need to use this solution I should know that for big arrays it can take some time.

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = 'USA';
foreach ($country as $k => $v) {
  if (strpos($v, $str) !== FALSE)
    break;
}

echo $k; // will print: 0
```

Comment: it fails when $str is never found in $country!

Comment: @DelPedro: Man, you're right! but I'm too lazy to correct the code. Let the chosen answerer fix that :)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't setting any keys in your example which means that the keys get automatically assigned a value from 0 to 3. And the value "USA" doesn't exist in your array, if you would do a search for "01. USA" then you would get the value 0 (zero) as it's the first value in your array with an automatically assigned key.

Do an array_search for "USA" on this array and it might give you the expected results:

`$country = array (1 => "USA", 2 => "Russia", 3 => "UK", 4 => "India");`

You need to use `key => value` to assign keys and values properly. Instead of `1 => "USA"` you can also do `"01" => "USA"` which will give USA the key "01".

Comment: and it is still unanswered. What if he gets such data from 3rd party datasource?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought the problem was with the keys. Having read his edit I understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use preg-grep as described here [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-grep.php).

you then should put the results of preg_grep into array_search.

```
$results = preg_grep($pattern, $input);
$indices = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
   $indices[] = array_search($result, $input);
}
```

Comment: Maybe? Are you guessing or answering?

Answer (score 1):

```
$search = "USA";
$country = array ("01. USA","02. Russia","03. UK","04. India");
foreach($country as $key=>$cnt){
   if(strpos($cnt,$search)){
      echo "String found in position $key";
      break;
   }
 }
```

You can write code in this way. But it will also return true If your search string is "US" also....

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to keep your current structure (Which is not the best solution) without any keys. Here's what you can do:

```
$countries = array (
                    "01. USA",
                    "02. Russia",
                    "03. UK",
                    "04. India"
                   );

$input  =  'UK';
$output =  '';
foreach ($countries as $country){
     $found = strpos($country,$input);
     if ($found > 0){  // assuming $country wouldn't start with country name.
         $output = trim(substr($country,0,$found-1));
         break;
     }
}
```

But, I believe everyone would suggest you to use Keys in array.