# PHP Array Search with key values

Tags: php

I have following arrays :

```
<?php 
$a=array(
    "abc"=>array("red","white","orange"),
    "def"=>array("green","vilot","yellow"),
    "xyz"=>array("blue","dark","pure")
); 

echo array_search(array("dark"),$a);

?>
```

How to get output of xyz in array list.

Comment: Possible DUPLICATE of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783747/php-array-search-get-key-value

Answer (score 1):

`array_search` returns false or the key. Since you have multiple dimensions you must loop through to get the lowest level.

Since we are in another dimension your return will actually be `1`. For this reason, if `array_search` succeeds we must use the key that is defined in the foreach

```
<?php
$a=array("abc"=>array("red","white","orange"),"def"=>array("green","vilot","yellow"),"xyz"=>array("blue","dark","pure")); 
foreach($a as $key=>$data){
    if(array_search("dark",$data)){
        echo $key;

    }    

}
```

Outputs: xyz

Answer (score 1):

You can create one user-define function to check value

```
 $a=array("abc"=>array("red","white","orange"),"def"=>array("green","vilot","yellow"),"xyz"=>array("blue","dark","pure")); 
 function search_data($value, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if(is_array($val) && in_array($value,$val))
       {
           return $key;
       }
   }
   return null;
}
echo search_data("dark",$a);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/ic4ai)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
function searchMultiArray($arrayVal,$val){
    foreach($arrayVal as $key => $suba){

        if (in_array($val, $suba)) {
         return $key;
     }

 }
}

$a = array("abc"=>array("red","white","orange"),"def"=>array("green","vilot","yellow"),"xyz"=>array("blue","dark","pure"));
echo $keyVal = searchMultiArray($a , "dark");
```